# angular.identity is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use the following...

.withHttpConfig({transformRequest: angular.identity})

but i always get **undefined is not a function** It does not seems to know what `angular.identity` is. Can anyone help?

full code:

```
angular.module('app.controllers.project', [
    "app.factories.storage",
    "app.factories.http",
    "app.directives.typeahead",
    "app.directives.projectDisplay",
    "toaster"


])



   .controller("projectController", ['$scope', '$rootScope', "$location",
        "httpFactory", "filterService", "$stateParams", "toaster",
        function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, httpFactory, filterService, $stateParams, toaster) {

            var createProject = function () {



                var resource = httpFactory
                    .withHttpConfig({transformRequest: angular.identity})
                    .post("project", data, {}, {'Content-Type': undefined})
                    .then(function () {
                        // do on success
                        console.log("done")
                    }, function () {
                        // do on failure
                         console.log("error")
                    });
etc
```

Comment: What angular version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`angular.identiy` is a very simple function which just returns its arguments.

Here is the source code of it: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L379

What happens if you change your code from

```
.withHttpConfig({transformRequest: angular.identity})
```

to

```
.withHttpConfig({transformRequest: function(arg) { return arg; } })
```